# Conditionally deleting tags from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a the following three tables in my database:

```
cases
  id   INT
  description   TEXT

tags
  id   INT
  name   TEXT

case_tag
  id   INT
  case_id   INT
  tag_id    INT
```

An individual case can have any number of tags and a tag may belong to any number of cases.

If a case is deleted, I want to remove any tags in the `tags` table that are linked to it if (and only if) they are not linked to any other case. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using InnoDB, create a referential action ON DELETE CASCADE between `case` and `case_tag`. Then after you have deleted the desired `case`, the corresponding `case_tag` rows will be deleted automatically, and all that remains is to simply:

```
DELETE FROM tag WHERE tag_id NOT IN (SELECT tag_id FROM case_tag);
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3491a/3)

You could even do it from a trigger if desired, but this method is better suited for some kind of background "cleanup" process, since it'll purge all the superfluous tags and not just the ones that were related to the last deleted `case`.

The alternative would be to pre-select the tags connected to the case being deleted, and then attempt to delete *only them*.

---

Incidental suggestions:

- TEXT (a form of BLOB) is probably an overkill for `tag.name` - use VARCHAR instead.
- You probably don't need the [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) `case_tag.id`.
- Consider adding an index on `case_tag {tag_id, case_id}` (i.e. opposite of the PK in my SQL Fiddle). Having `tag_id` at the **leading edge** of an index is important for enforcing the FK on `tag_id`, for selecting cases of a given tag and for the DELETE above. We include `case_id` to make the index more likely to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the query, and the `case_id` would be included in the index anyway since secondary indexes in [clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) tables include a copy of PK.
- Use singular when naming tables (or at least don't mix plural and singular).
- Use prefixes in PK field names. This is somewhat controversial, but in my experience increases the readability of the ER model, SQL and [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you very much. I have also taken on board your other suggestions.

Comment: I read the original question and compared it to the SQL Fiddle. This answer's SQL Fiddle does erase case 1. However, there is a problem. The original question says `If a case is deleted, I want to remove any tags in the tags table that are linked to it if (and only if) they are not linked to any other case`. The SQL Fiddle does not match the question because case1 and case2 share tags. I will explain further in my answer.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Yes they share 3 tags. The remaining (fourth) tag gets deleted.

Comment: Having thoroughly read the question again, this answer is correct. Tag3 should vanish and it does. My mistake for not reading more carefully. +1 !!!

Answer (score 1):

For this example, let's say you are deleting a case whose id is 127.

This query should give you all cases that have tags that are attached to case 127

## QUERY #1

```
SET @caseid_to_delete = 127;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @sharedtags_casecount
FROM (SELECT BB.case_id,B.tag_id
FROM case_tag AA INNER JOIN case_tag BB
ON  AA.case_id=@caseid_to_delete
AND AA.tag_id=BB.tag_id
AND AA.case_id<>BB.case_id) A;
```

If @sharedtags_casecount is 0, then it is OK to delete the case id and corresponding tags

## QUERY #2

```
DELETE C.*,T.* FROM cases C,case_tag CT,tags T
WHERE C.id=@caseid_to_delete
AND CT.case_id=@caseid_to_delete
AND CT.tag_id=T.id
AND @sharedtags_casecount=0;
```

## CAVEAT #1

You can run the DELETE query if @sharedtags_casecount > 0. It should not delete anything. Please back up the data and test it on a staging server.

## CAVEAT #2

Please make sure `case_tag` has a compound index on `case_id`,`tag_id`

```
ALTER TABLE case_tag ADD INDEX case_tag_ndx (case_id,tag_id);
```

## EPILOGUE

Once you have tested and verfied, the solution is simply the two queries executed consecutively

```
SET @caseid_to_delete = 127;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO @sharedtags_casecount
FROM (SELECT BB.case_id,BB.tag_id
FROM case_tag AA INNER JOIN case_tag BB
ON  AA.case_id=@caseid_to_delete
AND AA.tag_id=BB.tag_id
AND AA.case_id<>BB.case_id) A;
DELETE C.*,CT.* FROM cases C,case_tag CT,tags T
WHERE C.id=@caseid_to_delete
AND CT.case_id=@caseid_to_delete
AND CT.tag_id=T.id
AND @sharedtags_casecount=0;
```

## Give it a Try !!!

### UPDATE 2013-05-29 11:30 EDT

I looked at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16802636/491757) from [@Branko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533120/branko-dimitrijevic) and the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3491a/4) provided. The answer does not match the question. Why? In the SQL Fiddle, case1 and case2 share three tags (1,2,4). You said in the question

> If a case is deleted, I want to remove any tags in the tags table that are linked to it if (and only if) they are not linked to any other case.

Since `case1` and `case2` share tags, `case1` should not have been allowed to be deleted. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` mechanically performs deletes but cannot be adjusted to adhere to the stipulation of tags shared by nobody else. My solution adheres to it.

Here is [my SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14117/1) that demonstrates the following:

- Setting @caseid_to_delete to 1 forbids deleting `case1` because it shares tags with `case3`
- Setting @caseid_to_delete to 2 is OK because nobody else has `tag5` and `tag7`
- Setting @caseid_to_delete to 3 forbids deleting `case3` because it shares tags with `case1`
- Setting @caseid_to_delete to 4 is OK because nobody else has `tag6` and `tag8`
- Foreign keys are optional. `ON DELETE CASCADE` not needed.

I am sorry, but maybe the wording has me thinking of `case_tag` vs `tags` since the ON DELETE CASCADE is needed by `case_tag`.

### UPDATE 2013-05-29 11:36 EDT

I retract my argument because the question says delete from tags not case_tag. +1 for Branko's answer.

Comment: +1 for an equally valid solution and very thorough explanation. Really helpful, thanks.

Comment: `Since case1 and case2 share tags, case1 should not have been allowed to be deleted.` This is not implied from the question. A case is deleted in any case (no pun intended ;) ), the issue is only whether to also delete some tags (and which).

Answer (score 0):

try this sql

```
delete t.*
from tags t
inner join case_tag ct
on t.id=ct.tag_id
inner join cases c
on ct.case_id=c.id
and t.id not in(select distinct tag_id from case_tag where case_id<>1)
and ct.case_id=1;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab33f/1)

Comment: This style of `DELETE` is quite dangerous for two reasons: Reason1) The Query Optimizer tends to barf at DELETE-based/UPDATE-based self-referencing joins ( I wrote about this in the DBA StackExchange : dba.stackexchange.com/a/1384/877 ). In other words, there can be spurious results without a predictable pattern (may work for some ids and fail for others), Reason2) In MySQL Replication, there is no guarantee of row order. Thus, the last 10 rows might be different on a Slave than from that of its Master.